# Makefile: silence the "make[N]:" line specifically

Tags: makefile, silent

Part of my makefile has the following code:

```
target.o:
        cd dir; $(MAKE)
```

Where the file `target.o` has its own makefile inside of directory `dir`. During compiling, I get the following output lines:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `dir'
ifort -c target.f -o target.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `dir'
```

I would like to silent the first and third output lines but keep the second. Adding the -s to the make in the main makefile eliminates the first and third but also the one I want to keep.

(1) Is there a way to do this?

(2) Is there a reason why doing this might not be such a good idea?

Comment: `$(MAKE) --no-print-directory`?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Also: is there a way to silent just one of the two commands in `cd dir; $(MAKE) --no-print-directory`? Or a way to separate them in two lines but keep working on the same shell?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want `$(MAKE) --no-print-directory`.

> -w, --print-directory       Print the current directory.
>
> --no-print-directory        Turn off -w, even if it was turned on implicitly.

You cannot silence only part of a command. The `@` prefix is all-or-nothing.

You can echo anything you want of course (this is how the autotools silent output works for example, silence the default make output and then output `GEN target.file` or whatever).